# Making a currently being edited file the real file. (Through nano)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, nano

I have a file that is currently "being edited" by another instance. How do I make the file that is currently being edited the real file?

I want to make file `.foo.swp` the real file `foo`.

I was editing the file in nano.

Comment: Why would you want to? The point of `.foo.swp` is avoid non-atomic changes to `foo` to maintain consistency for other processes that might try to read it.

Comment: I copied a file from another server (using scp) and supposedly someone was already editing that file.

Comment: I would: a) save the current file under another name and quit nano, and b) reload (by scp) the file being edited by someone else once you are sure he is ready (i.e. the swap file disappeared). Now you will have to decide which one you keep, or even better: c) see the difference between both (with diff, v.gr.) and merge the changes, manually if there are few, by merging patches if there are a lot of changes in both versions.

Comment: I now have another file that was being edited when the PC went down. I now have the same problem...